# Go tutorial for Google App Engine: ImportError: No module named _md5

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to run the hello world tutorial for the Google app engine in Go language. The GAE SDK for go is based on python 2.5, which I installed. I then had to install openssl, but now when I try to run my sample application on the SDK, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named _md5
```

I even tried a simple import md5 & import hashlib from the python interpreter interface, and i still get the same error

```
>>> import hashlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/hashlib.py", line 133, in <module>
md5 = __get_builtin_constructor('md5')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/hashlib.py", line 60, in __get_builtin_constructor
import _md5
ImportError: No module named _md5
```

Does anybody know a workaround for this? Thank you!
I have a feeling that this problem is really about python installation than anything else

Comment: How did you install Python? Seems like it's missing the md5 C module.

Comment: Why you don't use `md5.py` not `_md5.py`?

Comment: _md5 is not a pure Python module, but a C extension.

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using ? on which platform ?

Comment: I'm using GAE's python based Go SDK, on Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with GAE, or the SDK. I have faced this before. If you tried to install your custom version of python (on Ubuntu), then you land up with such issues. You should uninstall the custom python using checkinstall. More details can be found about there here: [Uninstall python built from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544378/uninstall-python-built-from-source).

Just use the default python and you'll be fine!

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what happened, i was able to get it running simply by using the ubuntu version of python.