# Python: ImportError: No module named _md5

Tags: python

I have python 2.5.1 installed on my Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64 machine.

When i try to import hashlib/md5, the i get this error

```
>>> import hashlib 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/hashlib.py", line 133, in <module>
md5 = __get_builtin_constructor('md5')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/hashlib.py", line 60, in __get_builtin_constructor
import _md5
ImportError: No module named _md5
```

I have tried most of the solutions that I could find on google, but nothing works for me. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Did you build this Python yourself, or does it come from `apt-get`?

Comment: I downloaded the .tar file from the site and then ./configure, make and make install

Comment: Sorry, I should have known from the `/usr/local` in the error message.

Comment: This is probably due to an incompatible OpenSSL libraries in your install that's causing the python to not build `md5` (which is normally used) and not building `_md5` (which is built if OpenSSL wasn't found). Is there a reason that you want to build your own rather than using ubuntu's?

Comment: no, there's no specific reason for me to use my own, so how do I undo what I've installed so that i can install using apt-get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544378/uninstall-python-built-from-source

Comment: You don't need to install via apt-get, Ubuntu 10.04 should already have python installed in `/usr/bin` unless you did something very weird. You can try running `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: yeah, i guess i just complicated things by installing my own python, i just undid whatever i did, and everything's back to normal, thanks guys!

Comment: @birryree I am facing the same issue. I don't have root privileges, so I can't update the openssl package. I donloaded its(libssl-dev) source code and compiled it. Now how can I make sure that if I build python, it uses this newly generated libraries and not the one's in system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to have the package libssl-dev installed before configuring and compiling python from the tarball:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
cd YOUR_PYTHON_2.5_1_SRC_DIR
make clean
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Do you have a good reason not to use the latest version in the 2.5.X series?

Comment: +1 because you mentioned the obvious - why not use the version from apt.