# ImportError when attempting to install library python.

Tags: python, linux

I am attempting to use the pyexcel-ods library which I have downloaded from here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyexcel-ods

Calling 'pip install pyexcel-ods' as instructed or 'python setup.py install' results in the following output:[image: error printout]. As you can see the error seems to occur when the program attempts to import a module named _md5.

What would the correct method of installation be? Alternatively, is there a better way I can read information in from a ods file?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306531/python-importerror-no-module-named-md5 TL:DR: Your Python installation was probably not built with the necessary SSL support.

Answer (score 0):

---

> No module md5(.py)

Install `pycrypto` with pip, or install `pycrypto` with your 'OS Package Mangement' : "`python-crypto`"

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto

---