# uninstall python compiled by source

Tags: python, centos

My Centos installed two python2.7. I want to remove one. How can I do that?
Please note that both version are built from source I have viewed [Uninstall python built from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544378/uninstall-python-built-from-source) but it only talked about uninstall in Ubuntu.

Comment: how did you install them to which locations?

Comment: one install to /opt/python2.7
another one install to /usr/local/lib/python2.7