# Removing second python install

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

This morning I installed python3.3.2 from source, which is giving me some headaches, so now I want it removed. python3 launches python3.3.2, which is stored in /usr/local/bin. However, when I try to remove it, it wants to remove python3.3.1, stored in /usr/bin. I obviously want to keep this one.

```
$ which -a python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

How do I get 'sudo apt-install remove python3' to not remove the necessary 3.3.1 /usr/bin one, and only 3.3.2 one in /local/bin? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uninstall python built from source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544378/uninstall-python-built-from-source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed it from source, `apt-install` has no idea that it exists.

The easiest way (as most makefiles don't have an `uninstall` target) is to run `make install` again in your 3.3.2 source directory and capture what it sticks where and then remove them.

The cheaper way would be to `rm /usr/local/bin/python3` and probably anything else in `/usr/local/bin/py*` including symlinks to various parts of the suite.

Comment: I just did so, and now python3 doesn't start. $ which -a python3
/usr/bin/python3
but when I type python3, it still looks for /usr/home/bin/.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3` should clean that up.

Comment: or `bash$ hash -r` if your shell has remembered removed versions

Comment: Sadly not, I just reinstalled it and it gave the following response 'bash: /usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory'

Comment: Ah, the second one worked fine. I haven't seen that before, as you have probably guessed, I'm very new to linux, need to learn a lot about the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Incidentally the bash path cache managed by `hash` would have gone away if you had re-logged in. There's almost never a reason to use `hash` which is why many don't know of it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you compiled python3.3.2 from source so it's not registered with `aptitude`.

If you go to the directory where you ran `./configure && make && make install` simply run:

```
make uninstall
```

If this fails (or the python developers have not built for `make uninstall`), you can do the following:

1. Install checkinstall
2. Use checkinstall to make a deb of your Python installation
3. Use `dpkg -r` to remove the deb.

That answer was taken from this question [Uninstall python built from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544378/uninstall-python-built-from-source).

Comment: make uninstall didn't seem to work, but removing the directory worked anyway, it only contained the python installation. A bit of a hack, but it got the job done. Thanks anyway!