# Uninstalling PIL built from source

Tags: python, linux, python-imaging-library

I used this tutorial to install PIL. Now, I want to uninstall it and install `pillow` in its place.

```
mkdir -p ~/src ~/lib/python2.7
cd ~/src
wget http://effbot.org/media/downloads/PIL-1.1.7.tar.gz
tar zxf PIL-1.1.7.tar.gz
cd PIL-1.1.7
python2.7 setup.py build_ext -i
python2.7 setup.py install
```

How do I uninstall PIL?

PS: I haven't installed PIL in any of my virtualenvs. It is a global installation. I am using virtualenvs to all my projects, however.

Comment: If you can install [checkinstall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CheckInstall), you can [probably use it to remove PIL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3544440/190597).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from Ubuntu 14.04, but this should be generally applicable. When I installed, I called the following:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

I noted the following statements describing the default installation:

```
...
Installing pildriver.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing viewer.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing gifmaker.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing painter.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pilfont.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pilprint.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pilconvert.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing enhancer.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pilfile.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing createfontdatachunk.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing explode.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing thresholder.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing player.py script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pillow-3.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
```

So, I ran the following:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo rm -f pildriver.py viewer.py gifmaker.py painter.py pilfont.py pilprint.py pilconvert.py enhancer.py pilfile.py createfontdatachunk.py explode.py thresholder.py player.py
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pillow-3.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
```

After reinstalling Pillow (python-imaging) through apt-get, everything's running fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to manually remove all the files that were copied to your system. Also you need to edit some text files and manually remove references to the file.

There's no uninstall feature. Next time use your distribution's package management system.

Comment: Thanks. This was my only time I didn't use an automated install system (like pip). I had to do it that way. Can you be more specific what should I do?

Comment: @xpanta your linux distribution probably has a package management system, like debian/ubuntu has the dpkg/apt system, and redhat/mandriva has the rpm system. If you use those tools to install the software you want, you can easily remove it later by using the same tools.

Comment: @nosklo, could you please provide more details about what text files need to be edited and what files we should be looking for to remove?