# Error with scipy: No module named `imsave`

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am using the scipy module's `imread` and `imsave` utilities. I get the following error:

> No module named `imsave`.

I did a little googling and figured that the error was due to PIL/Pillow not being installed. I do:

```
sudo pip install Pillow.
```

I get the following message:

> Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

I am importing scipy's misc functionality to use the imread and imsave function.

```
    import scipy.misc
    import numpy as np
    I = np.load('image.npy')
    scipy.misc.imsave('test_image.jpg',I) #The error pops up here
    J = scipy.misc.imread('test_image.jpg')
```

I reinstalled scipy after this. I still get the No module named error.

EDIT 1: To make things clear, I uninstalled PIL by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169435/uninstalling-pil-built-from-source). I then uninstalled scipy. But, when I run `sudo apt install python-scipy python-pil`, it says that pil is already the latest. However, it is not in the path `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-package`.

EDIT 2: To answer Mark Mikofski's questions: 
I am using Python from the Terminal. I run the file from the Terminal.

```
    `which python`
```

gives me the following output

```
    `/home/raghuram/bin/python`.
```

Importing sys and doing what you tell gives the list of following outputs:

```
    /home/raghuram/lib/python2.7
    /home/raghuram/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
    /home/raghuram/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /home/raghuram/lib/python2.7/lib-old
    /home/raghuram/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
    /usr/lib/python2.7
    /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /home/raghuram/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    /home/raghuram/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Scipy's version is 0.19.0

Comment: What version of `scipy`? The current documentation suggests the `imread` and `imsave` methods are inside `scipy.misc`, so the correct method call may be [scipy.misc.imsave()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html)

Comment: How did you import `scipy`? How are you calling `imread()` and `imsave()`? Any code snippets you have may be helpful to providing a useful answer.

Comment: Yes, I am using scipy.misc.imsave after importing it.

Comment: How are you starting python? What do you get if you type `which python`? What do you get if in Python you import `sys` and then type `print "\n".join(sys.path)`? I want to see if you are using Python 2 or 3 and if `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` is on your `PYTHONPATH`. What version of scipy is it? What do you get if you import scipy and type `print scipy.__version__`?

Comment: I am using Python from the Terminal. I run the file from the Terminal. `which python` gives me the following output `/home/raghuram/bin/python`. Importing sys and doing what you tell gives the list of following outputs:

Comment: @MarkMikofski I couldn't answer your questions fully in the comment. I have edited the question to add the answers to your questions.

Comment: Your Python interpreter and site-packages are in a custom location (`/home/raghuram`) so you can install packages by either calling pip from Python as a module like `python -m pip install numpy scipy pillow` or by usind the pip `--install-option` with the distutils `--prefix` option like `pip install --install-option="--prefix=~" numpy scipy pillow` Good luck! I update my answer below, please let me know if that solves your problem by selecting it as the correct answer.

Comment: weird that your pip can't figure out that it shouldn't install into `/usr/local/` can you type `which pip` and see if it is in `/usr/local/bin` or /usr/bin` if it is, then you should upgrade by typing `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python` altho you might need to add `--no-check-certificate` if it fails because of HTTPS

Comment: I just realized that you will need to install blas first because pip won't use wheels if you use `--instal-option` so run `sudo apt install gfortran libblas-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-dev` if using `--prefix`.

Comment: Also you could just add `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to your `PYTHONPATH` using `sys.path.insert()` if you already have SciPy and Pillow in those folders

Comment: Which version of Linux are you using? Is it Ubuntu? Is it 16.04 LTS? Also, can you tell me what you get if you type `which pip`?

Comment: `which pip` gives me `/home/raghuram/bin/pip`. Yes, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Your inputs were of great help!! sys.path.insert for  `/usr/local` and `/usr/lib' along with the  `--prefix` option worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi [@Raghuram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1556826/raghuram),

Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks you for asking your question, and I hope that you find an answer. Here are some links to [asking questions from the StackOverflow help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking):

- Your [question might be off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because it has to do software on a particular plaform, so it might be better suited to [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)
- Your [question doesn't have any code in it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and it also doesn't have [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See the comments that ask about [what version of Python and scipy you're using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617307/cant-debug-this-error#comment74283841_43617307), how you installed them (Anaconda, system, etc?) and what platform you are on (Ubuntu? 16.04LTS?) and [what code you used (how did you import scipy?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617307/cant-debug-this-error#comment74284258_43617307).
- Although you mentioned you did some Googling, your question lacks a sense of rigor - see ["How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). *EG*. Provide links to the sites you searched from which you obtained your attempted solution (to install the Pillow/PIL fork) - this link could be useful to someone else with a similar issue, even though it didn't help you.

## Suggested solution

From your answer it appears that you are not using the system Python in `/usr/lib/python2.7` and that your packages have been installed using the [`--prefix` installation scheme](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-unix-the-prefix-scheme) into `/home/raghuram` and `/home/raghuram/local/`.

Unfortunately, pip will not use wheels if it gets `--install-option` so you will have to install BLAS first.

```
$ sudo apt install gfortran libblas-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-dev
```

Then try to use the [`--install-option` with pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-install-option) to pass the `--prefix` option to install.

```
$ pip install --install-option="--prefix=/home/raghuram/" numpy scipy pillow
```

Another perhaps easier option is to see where your python interpreter thinks site-packages should go. To do this, [`import site` and call `site.getsitepackages()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.getsitepackages). If `/home/raghuram` is in that list, then chances are you can just call pip from Python as a module using the `-m` option.

```
$ python -m pip install numpy scipy pillow
```

Finally, if all else fails, you can fall back on distutils, but this is tricky because you can't mix the scipy/numpy BLAS dependencies. They can only be either ATLAS, OpenBLAS, MKL, or etc., not a mix. To see what you are using, first `import scipy numpy` and then call `numpy.show_configs()` and `scipy.show_configs()`. It get's even trickier from here because you need to edit the `setup.cfg` to tell numpy/scipy where your BLAS is, so let's assume that you can remove both of these and start from scratch. First install the dependencies from your distro's repo; I think by default they will always build with ATLAS.

```
$ sudo apt install gfortran libblas-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-dev
```

Then download the numpy and scipy zip files from PyPI and extract. For each you need to enter the extracted folder and run:

```
$ python setup.py install --prefix=~
```

Now try to use `scipy.misc.imsave` like their help docstring example

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.misc import imsave
>>> help(imsave)  # view docstring
>>> # then hit q key to return to interpreter
>>> x = np.zeros((255, 255))
>>> x = np.zeros((255, 255), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> x[:] = np.arange(255)
>>> imsave('gradient.png', x)    
>>> rgb = np.zeros((255, 255, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> rgb[..., 0] = np.arange(255)
>>> rgb[..., 1] = 55
>>> rgb[..., 2] = 1 - np.arange(255)
>>> imsave('rgb_gradient.png', rgb)
```

*NB*: you can always search for [Ubuntu packages online](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) or using [`apt search`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html).

PS IMO you should probably remove any packages you've installed to system python using `sudo pip` and IMO never do that again. Check in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

PPS IMHO you should **never** install Python packages on Linux using `sudo`, instead either install from the software repository of your distro using `apt` or `yum`, install using the pip `--user` option or create a Python virtual environment with `virtualenv`. See [my AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95037/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-python-packages/116645#116645).

Comment: @Raghuram you will need to use the `--prefix=/home/raghuram` option since your `PYTHONPATH` points to `/home/raghuram`. Sorry, the `--home` option won't work because it puts site-packages in `<home>/lib/python/site-package` _not_ `python2.7/site-packages` note the "2.7" is missing. Also the `--user` options installs into `~/.local` with an extra "." (dot) before "local". The `--root` option is weird, not sure where it installs to.

Comment: One option I hadn't considered is to let Python tell pip where to go by calling pip as a module using `python -m pip install numpy scipy pillow` that might be easiest. Inside python import `site` and type `print site.getsitepackages()` and see what it says. If it includes `/home/raghuram/lib/python2.7/site-packages` then you know that `python -m pip install <blah>` will always work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `Pillow` through `conda` via:

`conda install Pillow`