# Python 2.6.6 and tkinter module

Tags: python, tkinter, xubuntu

I need to run an application written in python. When I try to load it from terminal I get this error:

```
      File "/usr/local/bin/soar", line 3, in <module>
         import form.main
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/form/main.py", line 14, in <module>
         from Tkinter import *
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
         import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

I installed python 2.6.6 from the source files. I am really confused!!

How should I install tkinter?

I am running Xubuntu 13.10. You can see the different versions of python already installed in the below:

[image: Python error]

How can I remove python2.6.6? I tried to remove all files and folders related to python2.6. Now when I run python, it still loads python 2.6.6 I really have no idea what to do!! I tried to follow the instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7635985#post7635985) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544378/uninstall-python-built-from-source) to uninstall it but it did not work, that's why I deleted all the files and folders manually.
[image]

Comment: what happens if you run your program using python 2.7, like `python2.7 soar`?

Comment: @Fiver Before installing 2.6.6 it loaded the GUI but it was not working properly. After installing 2.6.6, when I try to run it with 2.7 it says it can no load soar!
I am trying a lot of different things. I think I have changed something, that's why it does not run it with 2.7.

Comment: I know this is almost 10 years later, but: "How should I install tkinter?" By installing the *development* dependency *before recompiling* the local install. System packages like `python-tk` only upgrade the system Python. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Install `python3-tk` package if you need *Tkinter* functionality in the 3rd version of python.

Comment: I have already done that. nothing changes. I still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe You have to install Tcl and Tk. see more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5459513/1832058

Comment: Yeah, maybe. But first I have to uninstall the python before I build it again, No?